# Laravel attempt to assign property of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to allow user to update their profile created on a page however I get an error message saying that i am trying to attempt to assign property of non-object:

[image]

But user and twitter do have a value.

In a database field is called twitter_personal and of course id is a id.

Controller:

```
function updateProfile(Request $request) {
    $user = Auth::id();
    $twitter = $request->input('twitter');
    $user->twitter_personal = $twitter;
    $user->save();
    if($user->save()) {
    $message = 'Success';
    }else{
    $message = 'Error';
    }
   return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('message', $message);
```

}

Form:

```
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ action('ProfileController@updateProfile') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('url') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="twitter" class="col-md-4 control-label">Twitter</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="twitter" type="text" class="form-control" name="twitter">
                @if ($errors->has('url'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('url') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

So here's the question, how can I solve it? and is there a better way of doing it? if so please provide an example!

Comment: `$user` is `Auth::id()` which is an id. It should be `Auth::user()`

Comment: true, works fine. Is that function a good practice? or it can be done better using another method //edit put it as a answer so i can mark it

Comment: Some people argue that using facades is not good practice. I think it's fine in laravel. In case you want to avoid using the `Auth` facade you can probably just do : `$request->user()` instead

Comment: Yeap you were right! thanks for a tip and put all that as an answer

Comment: Don't call `$user->save();` again in the check. Instead save the return value and use it `$result = $user->save();` and `if($result ) {`. It's very common to use the Auth facade or helper functions to get the current user and there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Przemek you should accept apokryfoxs's answer as well as Sandeesh is very correct .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `Auth::id()` will return the identifier of the currently authenticated user.

If you need to user model instead you should user:

```
 Auth::user()
```

If you instead prefer to not use the `Auth` facade you can just get the user associated with the current request:

```
$request->user()
```